# Ioshed 2012 HomeActivity.class not found

Tags: java, android

I got sources to explore http://code.google.com/p/iosched/. I haven't changed anything in manifest or code, so:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.google.android.apps.iosched"

    ....

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

    ....

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Iosched.Home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I built the project and installed on several devices(gb,icm). When launched it says:

> 06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.iosched/com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.HomeActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.HomeActivity 06-03 14:51:40.457:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
>   06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 06-03
>   14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-03
>   14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-03 14:51:40.457:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 06-03
>   14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-03
>   14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-03 14:51:40.457:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 06-03
>   14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-03 14:51:40.457:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1442): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.HomeActivity 06-03 14:51:40.457:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 06-03
>   14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 06-03
>   14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
>   06-03 14:51:40.457: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):   ... 11 more

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.HomeActivity" It seems weird since the class is present.

Could you suggest anything?

ps I tried to clean and fix properties but in vain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am getting the same kind of issues with Eclipse and that is because I haven't selected to export compatibility package. `Eclipse -> Right click on project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export -> Make sure "Private Libraries" are checked`.

The idea is that the activity is there alright, the problem is that the FragmentActivity is not present in final apk file.

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Iosched.Home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

if this doesn't work then use this

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.apps.iosched.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Iosched.Home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```